# What is the Query to read or return Salesforce object's fields (columns) and values using python

Tags: python, dictionary, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am trying to execute a select query on salesforce object as

```
from simple-salesforce import Salesforce as slf

slf_conn = slf(username=slf_username, password=slf_password, security_token=slf_security_token)

query = f"SELECT New_f_name__c, LastName__c, New_L_name__c, new_date_field__c, ID__c FROM Transformation__c "
slf_data = slf_conn.query_all(query)
print(slf_data)
```

this returns me the output as

```
{
    "records": [
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0tFpAAJ",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", "xyz"),
                ("LastName__c", "abc"),
                ("New_L_name__c", "pqr"),
                ("new_date_field__c", None),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0tFqAAJ",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", "ABC"),
                ("LastName__c", "UIQDD"),
                ("New_L_name__c", "LGD"),
                ("new_date_field__c", None),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0vjQAAR",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", None),
                ("LastName__c", None),
                ("New_L_name__c", None),
                ("new_date_field__c", "2001-02-11"),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0vjRAAR",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", None),
                ("LastName__c", None),
                ("New_L_name__c", None),
                ("new_date_field__c", "2005-03-17"),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0vjSAAR",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", None),
                ("LastName__c", None),
                ("New_L_name__c", None),
                ("new_date_field__c", "2018-08-14"),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
```

Is there a way such that i could retrieve the values as

```
{
    "records": [
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0tFpAAJ",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", "xyz"),
                ("LastName__c", "abc"),
                ("New_L_name__c", "pqr"),
                ("new_date_field__c", "2001-02-11"),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
        OrderedDict(
            [
                (
                    "attributes",
                    OrderedDict(
                        [
                            ("type", "Transformation__c"),
                            (
                                "url",
                                "/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Transformation__c/a005g00003D0tFqAAJ",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                ),
                ("New_f_name__c", "ABC"),
                ("LastName__c", "UIQDD"),
                ("New_L_name__c", "LGD"),
                ("new_date_field__c", "2005-03-17"),
                ("ID__c", None),
            ]
        ),
```

rather than having separate records based on each data type i want them together for each row or atleast have them in this order.
I tried to search for different execution methods but couldn't find any as i'm trying to copy the values of column and values storing them in a single row but because it returns in order of datatypes the values are not getting populated correctly for each row.